# Why is it running on start?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the script it runs the seconds script automatically. I'm trying to make it a title screen that you can start the game by clicking the start button, but when I run the program it starts the second program automatically. It doesn't do this with the other buttons I have, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Code is below**

```
from tkinter import *
import other_modules.Main

#Define Background Main Screen Color


root = Tk()
root.title("Root")
root.configure(background= "deep sky blue")
root.minsize(800, 500)  # width, height
root.maxsize(1200, 700)
root.geometry("300x300+50+50") 
root.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


#Background Colors Commands!!!
def BgLBlue():
    root.configure(background = "deep sky blue")
    Title = Label(root, text="Game", font=("Ariel",45), bg="deep sky blue")
    Title.grid(row=1, padx=55, pady=30)

def BgRed():
    root.configure(background = "Red")
    Title = Label(root, text="Game", font=("Ariel",45), bg="Red")
    Title.grid(row=1, padx=55, pady=30)

def BgGreen():
    root.configure(background = "Green")
    Title = Label(root, text="Game", font=("Ariel",45), bg="Green")
    Title.grid(row=1, padx=55, pady=30)

#Commands
def ColorMenu():
    #Colors Menu
    Color = Tk()
    Color.title("Color")
    Color.configure(background="saddle brown")
    Color.minsize(400, 250)  # width, height
    Color.maxsize(1200, 700)
    Color.geometry("100x100+500+500") 
    Color.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    Color.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #Colors Buttons
    Lblue = Button(Color, bg = "deep sky blue", text="     ", command = BgLBlue)
    Lblue.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    Red = Button(Color, bg = "red", text="     ", command = BgRed)
    Red.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    Green = Button(Color, bg = "SpringGreen2", text="     ", command = BgGreen)
    Green.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

def Startgame():
    other_modules.Main

def Optionsmenu():
    #Menu Screen
    options = Tk()
    options.title("options")
    options.configure(background="snow")
    options.minsize(400, 250)  # width, height
    options.maxsize(1200, 700)
    options.geometry("100x100+500+500") 
    options.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
    options.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #Options Buttons
    BgColor = Button(options, text ="Colors!", command = ColorMenu, font=("Ariel",11), bg = "gray82")
    BgColor.grid(row=3, padx=55, pady=30)

def QuitCom():
    root.quit()

#Options Menu
##Background Color

#Title
Title = Label(root, text="Game", font=("Ariel",45), bg="deep sky blue")
Title.grid(row=1, padx=55, pady=30)

#BUTTONS DO NOT MESS THEM UP!!!
Start = Button(root, text ="Start", command = Startgame, font=("Ariel",11), bg = "gray82")
Start.grid(row=2, padx=55, pady=30,)
#
Options = Button(root, text ="Options", command = Optionsmenu, font=("Ariel",11), bg = "gray82")
Options.grid(row=3, padx=55, pady=30)
#
Quitgame = Button(root, text ="Quit", command = QuitCom, font=("Ariel",11), bg = "gray82")
Quitgame.grid(row=4, padx=55, pady=30)


root.mainloop()
```

**The Startgame() is the problem**
Once I run this script, other_modules.Main runs. I want it only to start when the start button is clicked.

Comment: The statement `other_modules.Main` doesn't actually do anything (other than verifying that the `other_modules` object has an attribute named `Main`).  Assuming that this is a function, you need to put parentheses after it to actually call that function.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `other_modules.Main`. It's probably missing an `if __name__ == '__main__':` check to prevent it from running when it's imported.

Comment: Your `Startgame()` function doesn't make much sense. Even if you add `()`, it won't work because `other_modules.Main` is a module, not a function.

Comment: `Startgame()` should call `other_modules.Main.something()`, where `something()` is the name of the function in `other_modules.Main` that starts the game.

Comment: You had too many instances of `Tk` in every function. It should `= Toplevel` instead of `= Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to actually execute the code inside that module. Change the `Startgame` function to this:

```
def Startgame():
    other_modules.Main.main()
```

make sure that the `other_modules` directory is in the same directory as your main script